# Importing cantera (package) in google colab not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, google-colaboratory, cantera

I am not able to solve the following problem:
For my research I would like to use a **Google Colab** notebook to perform my data analysis.
To this end I need a package (**cantera**), which could only be installed using **conda**.
I am able to do this, however every time I start the colab notebook I need to reinstall all the packages again which takes a lot of time. Since I want to avoid this I followed a procedure described in this link: [https://dvij-kalaria.medium.com/how-to-make-load-save-a-conda-environment-in-google-colab-jupyter-322801aad486](https://github.com/luukalt/colab_env/blob/main/files.zip).

The goal is to:

1. create an environment with all the desired packages *once*. [create_environment.ipynb]
2. export these packages in a .zip to my google drive.
3. extract the .zip file containing the packages in a new colab notebook. [main_file]
4. run the notebook with the desired packages.

When following these steps it will show an error:

```
CanteraError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-9ed24c0ae5c4> in <module>()
      1 import cantera as ct
----> 2 gas = ct.Solution('gri30.cti')
      3 
      4 # Set reactants state
      5 gas.TPX = 298, 101325, 'CH4:1, O2:2'

interfaces/cython/cantera/base.pyx in cantera._cantera._SolutionBase.__cinit__()

interfaces/cython/cantera/base.pyx in cantera._cantera._SolutionBase._init_cti_xml()

CanteraError: 
***********************************************************************
CanteraError thrown by call_ctml_writer:
Error converting input file "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cantera/data/gri30.cti" to CTML.
Python command was: '/usr/bin/python3'
The exit code was: 1
-------------- start of converter log --------------
sys.path: ['', '/env/python', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cantera'
--------------- end of converter log ---------------
***********************************************************************
```

While if I run a code cell containing:

```
!pip show cantera
```

I get the following output:

```
Version: 2.5.1
Summary: The Cantera Python Interface
Home-page: https://cantera.org
Author: Raymond Speth
Author-email: speth@mit.edu
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

Indicating that the cantera package is found.

The files (.ipynb) to replicate the problem are found on my Github page: [files.zip](https://github.com/luukalt/colab_env/blob/main/files.zip)

I really hope someone can help me out on this one!

Comment: You may have better luck with a maintained solution such as https://github.com/conda-incubator/condacolab, which is designed specifically for this purpose

Comment: But doesnt this take a long time each time I need to open and run the notebook?

Comment: I tried your proposal (building the constructor with the cantera pacakge), but it still did not import cantera correctly (results in the same error in call_ctml_writer)